# How to extract literal type from property value of a typed object?

Tags: typescript

```js
type Animal = { name: string } // imported from 3rd party module


const cat: Animal = {
    name: 'Cat' as const,
}


const dog = {
    name: 'Dog' as const
}

type CatName = typeof cat.name // = string, not 'Cat' !!!
type DogName = typeof dog.name // = 'Dog'
```

In above code, how can I get a literal type `CatName = 'Cat'` (like `DogName = 'Dog'`)?

Note: I can't change the definition of type `Animal` because it's 3rd party code, and I'd like to keep the value `cat` to be typed.

Comment: It is only possible, if you use a generic helper function to create the objects. When you type an object as `Animal` the information about values of specific properties will be lost since `Animal` defines `name` as `string`.

Comment: Why not define `CatName` and `DogName` as constants first - `const CatName = 'Cat'; const cat: Animal = {name: CatName};`?

Comment: `const CatName = 'Cat'` and `const CatName = 'Cat' as const` are the same thing

Comment: Okay, I will try the generic helper function as @tobias-s suggested.

Comment: @TobiasS. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I'd like to keep the value cat to be typed

If you explicitly type `cat` *as `Animal`*, then no, you can't get `'Cat'` out. You can type it more precisely `const cat: { name: 'Cat' }` (which is a subtype of `Animal`) or even `const cat: Animal & { name: 'Cat' }` if you want to be explicit it's an `Animal`.

Comment: Okay, I guess this might be the easiest way.

Comment: Actually, what's wrong with Iain Shelvington's suggestion (with added `type CatName = typeof CatName` to make it usable as a type)?